# header not working online but works perfect in localhost

Tags: php

I am creating a doc in php. My code works fine in localhost but it doesn't work when i put it to online. I guess the header is not working properly. How to resolve this issue .The problem is with the adding content-type and content-disposition in header. Any way to add those in a different way ?  My code is given below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=Productname.doc");
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "EUC-JP", "auto"); 
$conn = oci_connect("NPM_OPL", "NPM_OPL", "192.168.10.35:1521/pdbopl");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style>
        @font-face { font-family: Solaimanlipi; src: url('SolaimanLipi.ttf'); } 
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;

        font-size-adjust:inherit;
        font-size:12px;
        }

        table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        th {
        font-weight:normal !important;
        }
</style>

</head>
<body>



<?php
    for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['max_item'];$i++){  
    $check=$_POST['check_'.$i];
    if(!empty($check)){
    $STATUS=$_POST['STATUS_'.$i];   
    $srlno=$_POST['SLNO_'.$i];      
    if($STATUS=='M'){
?>




<?php   



 ?>
```

Comment: naming a file *.doc does not magically make it a proper word file

Comment: what the error message you are getting ?

Comment: @MohdSayeed the site can not be reached.might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: @Dagon how does it create it in localhost then ?

Comment: its not a real word file, your just lucky that *some* versions of word may interpret the html correctly.

Comment: @Dagon: Can you suggest me any libary in php to create a proper doc file?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord